# how do i prevent react native model running multiple times inside the flat list?

Tags: react-native, button, react-native-flatlist, react-native-modal

Here is my model

```
           <View style={styles.centeredView}>
              <Modal
                animationType="slide"
                transparent={true}
                visible={modalVisible}

                onRequestClose={() => {
                  Alert.alert('Modal has been closed.');
                  setModalVisible(!modalVisible);

           }}>
```

when i click this share button model is opening until come all item inside the flat list.
here the share button

```
         <Button
          style={[styles.buttons, styles.buttonClose]}
          onPress={handleSubmit}
          disabled={!isValid}
          title="Share"
         />
```

Here the flat list

```
<FlatList
    data={newPost}
    renderItem={({ item ,  index}) =>

  //rest of code

   keyExtractor={item => item._id}
/>
```

I need to stop model opening more than one.Please help me

here the handleSubmit()

```
 const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);

 const handleSubmit = (values) => {

const formData = {

  firstN: values.firstN,
  secondN: values.secondN,
  thirdN: values.thirdN,
  firstT: values.firstT,
  secondT: values.secondT,
  thirdT: values.thirdT,
  event: values.event,
  date: "2027-12-12 19:10:00",
  description: values.description,
  type: values.type,
  gender: values.gender,

}

axios.post(`${BASE_URL}pastevents/post`, formData)
  .then(data => {
    console.log(" success ")
    setModalVisible(!modalVisible);
  }
  )
  .catch(err => console.log(err))



}
```

Comment: Please provide more information. I can't see enough info about the problem. what happens when "handleSubmit" function runs? When "modalVisible" state change? etc..

Comment: now you can see